# Tkinter get value from Radiobutton and Entry

Tags: tkinter, return-value

Enjoying my time working on project with pandas and tkinter that will work as single executable later on, the plan is user selects Radiobutton and add quantity entry I am selecting excel sheet based on user selection and extracting rows based on entered quantity. But stuck on radio buttons and get back the user input what's the normal way doing it? Please see code below, thanks in advance:

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
#Creating UI
root = Tk()
#Assign variable to return value from radiobuttons 
r = StringVar()
#Set to None on loading selection to be empty
r.set(None)


#Crating Radiobuttons 
r1 = Radiobutton(root,text='A', variable=r, value='A', command=lambda: r.get())
r1.pack(anchor = NW)
r2 = Radiobutton(root,text='B', variable=r, value='B', command=lambda: r.get())
r2.pack(anchor = NW)
r3 = Radiobutton(root,text='C', variable=r, value='C', command=lambda: r.get())
r3.pack(anchor = NW)
r4 = Radiobutton(root,text='D', variable=r, value='D', command=lambda: r.get())
r4.pack(anchor = NW)

inp_box = Entry(root, width = 20)
inp_box.pack(anchor = CENTER)

def create_frame():
    path = 'file.xlsm'
    num_rows = inp_box.get()
    df = pd.read_excel(path, str(r.get()))
    df.head()
    print(num_rows)

btn_rep = Button(root, text = "Report", width=100, command=create_frame())
btn_rep.pack(anchor=SW)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `inp_box.get()` should return the input text and you can use `r.get()` inside `create_frame()` to get which radiobutton is selected.

Comment: @acw1668 doesn't work what i am doing wrong? Updated Main post

Comment: What do you mean by *"doesn't work"*? Any error? Also `command=create_frame()` should be `command=create_frame` instead.

Comment: Sorry forgot that I am using .py instead  of .ipynb my bad work file thanks sir

Comment: `command=lambda: r.get()` for those radiobuttons is useless and can be removed.

Comment: Ok tnx will do, we don't invoke the function we only make the reference to it , radio btn, does not need a command because they  have saved their value in variable r

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was posted by @acw1668
inp_box.get() should return the input text and you can use r.get() inside create_frame() to get which radiobutton is selected. –